# Math.Round a label in C#

Tags: c#, math, methods

i am trying to round my output to 2 decimals in C#. My code works correctly, it writes what i want to my label, but it refuses to round it to 2 decimals. Can anyone help me with this? The commented math.round code is what I tried an got no errors with. It doesn't work for me tho.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        double input;
        double number = 0.484;
        double output;
        input = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        output = Convert.ToDouble(input / number);
        label1.Text = output.ToString();
        //output = Math.Round(output, 2);
        //Math.Round(output, 2);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Do nothing
```

Comment: 1) `ToString` takes a format string which can be used to display two digits 2) If you care about the number of decimal digits in actual numbers, consider using `decimal` over `double`. 3) Are you really assigning from `output` to `label1.Text` before you round `output`? That can't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is too late to round the output after you have set its pre-rounding value to the label. You need to round the value first, and then set it, like this:

```
label1.Text = Math.Round(output, 2).ToString();
```

However, rounding for display purposes is not the best way of doing things: you would be better off formatting the value to two decimal places.

Comment: @Luaan It generally works even with doubles (though it doesn't print trailing zeros), but is generally a bad idea. Any call to `Math.Round(double, digits)` is a flaw in the code as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: According to this it will work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Oh, you're right that for rounding to two digits, it will usually work. However, it's not the right way to do this. For example, `Math.Round(6987987946546541.9321, 2).ToString()` will return `6.98798794654654E+15`, while `Math.Round(6987987946546541.9321, 2).ToString("f2")` returns `6987987946546540.00`.

Answer (score 3):

You should write the output formatted:

```
label1.Text = output.ToString("N2");
```

Or, if you don't want `CultureInfo` thousands separator:

```
label1.Text = output.ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this to get 2 decimals

```
label1.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}%", output.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
 label1.Text = output.ToString("#.##");
```

Change this statment it will work fine.